# Django Global function and variable

Tags: python, django

I have one function in my view. I want to use this function in some other apps. Is there any way to declare this variable (`shop_id`)  globally.

```
if "current_shop" in request.session:
    shop_id = request.session['current_shop']
elif request.user.is_superuser:
    shop_id = 1
else:
    shop_id = 2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make it a function your views use; return the `shop_id` value from the function:

```
def get_shop_id(request):
    if "current_shop" in request.session:
        return request.session['current_shop']

    return 1 if request.user.is_superuser else 2
```

and in your views:

```
shop_id = get_shop_id(request)
```

If you put this in a separate module; say `utils.py`, you can import it with:

```
from projectname.utils import get_shop_id
```

or using a relative import:

```
from .utils import get_shop_id
```

provided `utils.py` lives in the same package as your views.

Comment: Yes, put it in a separate file ( utils.py ? ) inside your app, and then you can do `from my_app.utils import get_shop_id`